# Determine Starting IP/Ending IP address of an IPv6 CIDR Notated value in C#

Tags: c#, ipv6, biginteger, cidr

I am trying to determine the Starting IP address and Ending IP address of an IPv6 CIDR Notated value in C# (such as, `2001:5::/32`). If I put that value into [this website](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6CIDRToRangeResult?ipAddress=2001%3A5%3A%3A%2F32), I get:

```
Start Range: 2001:5:0:0:0:0:0:0
End Range: 2001:5:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
No. of host: 79228162514264337593543950336
```

When I run it through my method, I am getting `32.1.0.5` for both the start and end. My guess is it has to do with turning my results into a byte array. How can I make this better to work for me?

```
private bool GetIPAddressFromCIDR( string ipCIDR, out string startIP, out string endIP )
{
    startIP = endIP = "";
    try
    {
        string strAddress = ipCIDR.Substring( 0, ipCIDR.IndexOf( '/' ) );

        byte routingBitCount = Byte.Parse( ipCIDR.Substring( ipCIDR.IndexOf( '/' ) + 1 ) );
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse( strAddress );


        if( ipAddress.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6 )
        {
            BigInteger ip = new BigInteger( ipAddress.GetAddressBytes() );

            byte BitSize = 128;
            BigInteger mask;
            if( routingBitCount == 0 )
            {
                mask = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                mask = unchecked( ~( ( 1 << routingBitCount ) - 1 ) );
            }

            BigInteger start = ip & mask;
            BigInteger end = ip | ~mask;

            startIP = new IPAddress( start.ToByteArray() ).ToString();
            endIP = new IPAddress( end.ToByteArray() ).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            byte BitSize = 32;

            uint address = BitConverter.ToUInt32( ipAddress.GetAddressBytes(), 0 );
            uint mask = routingBitCount == 0 ? 0 : unchecked( ~( ( ( uint ) 1 << ( BitSize - routingBitCount ) ) - 1 ) );
            uint start = address & mask;
            uint end = start | ~mask;

            startIP = new IPAddress( start ).ToString();
            endIP = new IPAddress( end ).ToString();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**PS. No Libraries please. I want to make this code work**

Comment: If you use a bitwise `AND` with `CIDR` number of ones and `(128 - CIDR)` number of zeroes, then you end up with the starting address. To get the last address, use a bitwise `OR` with `CIDR` number of zeroes and `(128 - CIDR)` number of ones.

Comment: Anyway you could use my code to show me what you are talking about, because I thought that is what I am doing? The number translated to a byte array gives me an IPv4 Number.

Comment: One of the problems (but not the only one) is how BigInteger represented as byte array. First, it's always little endian, but ip address GetAddressBytes returns bytes in big-endian order (so you need to reverse). Then, BigInteger is signed type, you can read how this affects its byte representation here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.tobytearray(v=vs.110).aspx. Then, BigInteger is not fixed-size type (unlike int for example which is always 32 bits) - that also introduces its own problems. All that makes BigInteger not the best candidate for your task.

Comment: Is there a way to split the Byte Array into two ulong values? I know if I could get two 64 bit values I can do the math right. I am just not sure how to split it.